# Can I send unencrypted nonce in AES-GCM?

Tags: cryptography, aes-gcm, python-cryptography

I'm implementing AES-GCM in a simple chat.  Since there is no problem in the nonce being public and I need to change it in every message, can I send the message nonce unencrypted with the message itself?

An example:

There is a function like this:

```
AESGCM(nonce, key, data_to_encrypt, unencrypted_data)
```

And I use this way:

```
message = AESGCM(nonce, key, data, nonce)
```

Then, the encrypted message will look like this:

```
unencrypted_nonce | encrypted_data | authentication_tag
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AES-GCM documentation mentions nonce 3 times;

> A value that is used only once within a specified context.
>
> The IV is essentially a nonce

```
AESGCM(nonce, key, data, unencrypted_data)
```

The AES-GCM internally uses AES in CTR mode of operation, CTR mode turns a block cipher into a stream cipher. For the AES-GCM security and the CTR mode a nonce ( number used once) must be used only once per key. A nonce-key pair should only occur once. If a nonce repeats this can cause

1. Confidentiality fails due to the crib-dragging like all stream ciphers.
2. [Even a single AES-GCM nonce reuse can be catastrophic.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/68525/18298)

The nonce can be randomly generated, however, a counter/LFSR based solution is better, and a better one is the [combination](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/79887/18298).

- If you send the `nonce` encrypted how do you expect to decrypt the message. It must be sent unencrypted.

Comment: My doubt is if I can send the nonce unencrypted with the encrypted data

Comment: That is the point. Then why not encrypt the IV used to encrypt the old IV? As explained (the IV can be known to an attacker without breaking security.)(https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5094/is-aes-in-cbc-mode-secure-if-a-known-and-or-fixed-iv-is-used?noredirect=1&lq=1) you don't increase the security.